# Change formatting on paragraphs, with perl

Tags: perl

I have a number of paragraphs that have returns at the end of a line. I do not want returns at the end of lines, I will let the layout program take care of that. I would like to remove the returns, and replace them with spaces.

The issue is that I do want returns in between paragraphs. So, if there is more than one return in a row (2, 3, etc) I would like to keep two returns.

This would allow for there to be paragraphs, with one blank line between then, but all other formatting for lines would be removed. This would allow the layout program to worry about the line breaks, and not the have the breaks determined by a set number of characters, as they are now.

I would like to use Perl to accomplish this change, but am open to other methods.

example text:

```
This is a test.
This is just a test.

This too is a test.
This too is just a test.
```

would become:

```
This is a test. This is just a test.

This too is a test. This too is just a test.
```

Can this be done easily?

Comment: Yes this can be done easily. Have you written any code? Is there part of it you are having trouble with? StackOverflow isn't a free coding service.

Comment: My level of experience is limited. I have tried this in the past:

Comment: perl -p -i -e 's/(\w+|\s+)[\r\n]/$1 /g' abc.txt

The issue is mostly the same as the example that I tried below. It looks like it should do more than it is. In this case, it does add spaces for all of the returns, but does not remove the returns.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I came up with another solution and also wanted to explain what your regex was matching.

```
Matt@MattPC ~/perl/testing/8
$ cat input.txt
This is a test.
This is just a test.

This too is a test.
This too is just a test.



another test.
test.

Matt@MattPC ~/perl/testing/8
$ perl -e '$/ = undef; $_ = <>; s/(?<!\n)\n(?!\n)/ /g; s/\n{2,}/\n\n/g; print' input.txt
This is a test. This is just a test.

This too is a test. This too is just a test.

another test. test.
```

---

I basically just wrote a perl program and mashed it into a one-liner. It would normally look like this.

```
# First two lines read in the whole file
$/ = undef;
$_ = <>;

# This regex replaces every `\n` by a space
# if it is not preceded or followed by a `\n`
s/(?<!\n)\n(?!\n)/ /g;

# This replaces every two or more \n by two \n
s/\n{2,}/\n\n/g;

# finally print $_
print;
```

---

```
perl -p -i -e 's/(\w+|\s+)[\r\n]/$1 /g' abc.txt
```

Part of the problem here is what you are matching. `(\w+|\s+)` matches one of more word characters, which is the same as `[a-zA-Z0-9_]`, **OR** one or more whitespace characters, which is the same as `[\t\n\f\r ]`.

This wouldn't match your input, since you aren't matching periods, and no line consists of only white space or only characters (even the blank lines would need two whitespace characters to match it, since we have `[\r\n]` at the end). Plus, neither would match a period.

Comment: Your one liner can be simplified with switches to : `perl -0777 -pe 's/(?<!\n)\n(?!\n)/ /g; s/\n{2,}/\n\n/g;' input.txt`

Answer (score 1):

Using a perl one-liner.  Replace 2 or more newlines with just 2.  Strip all single newlines:

```
perl -0777 -pe 's{(\n{2})\n*|\n}{$1//" "}eg' file.txt > newfile.txt
```

**Switches**:

- `-0777`: Slurps the entire file
- `-p`: Creates a `while(<>){...; print}` loop for each “line” in your input file.
- `-e`: Tells `perl` to execute the code on command line.

Comment: I am not sure if it is an issue with a non-standard return being used or not, but the result of running the script above is not removing the returns at the end of the lines, making the paragraphs into basically one line. I do not see a change in the text I am using this against.

This is being used on a linux machine. I tried it with and without the -0777, but the results seem to be the same. Is there a possibility that the issue is that for whatever reason perl is not registering the return, because of it being non-standard in someway?

Comment: If you think that carriage returns could be an issue, then you could try changing any reference to `\n` above into `(?:\r?\n)`.  But the one-liner I provided works fine on my system for the example data you suggested.

Comment: I think I had originally tired: perl -0777 -pe 's/(\n{2})\n*|\n/$1/g'. When I use: perl -0777 -pe 's{(\n{2})\n*|\n}{$1//" "}eg', I et spaces with all of the returns, but not the elimination of the returns.

Comment: Your suggested change for the returns are:

perl -0777 -pe 's{(?:\r?\n{2})\n*|\n}{$1//" "}eg' test.txt > out.txt

?

Comment: My example was very simple, and could be the cause of the confusion. Below is a short selection from the book. I was going to include more, but there is an upper limit for the example.

'While he plied his brush for many years after the conception of his
epoch-making invention, it was with an ever lessening enthusiasm, with a
divided interest. Art no longer reigned supreme; Invention shared the
throne with her and eventually dispossessed her.'

Comment: No, my suggested change was: `perl -0777 -pe 's{((?:\r?\n){2})(?:\r?\n)*|(?:\r?\n)}{$1//" "}eg' file.txt > newfile.txt`